# How to select non null rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
Shop_name         Bikes_available             Shop_location       Average_price_of_bikes   Rating_of_shop

NYC Velo          Ninja,hbx                      Salida                   5685$               4.2               
Bike Gallery      dtr,mtg,Harley Davidson        Portland                 6022$               4.8
```

This dataset is stored in dataframe named df. I am tying to create new dataframe that contains only those rows whose shop name, bikes_available and shop_location values are not null

```
xtrain = df[df['Shop_name','Bikes_available','Shop_location']!=NULL]
```

Its showing keyerror: ('Shop_name','Bikes_available','Shop_location')

Comment: Check out `notna()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, select multiple columns use `[[]]`. Then, test for non missing values by [`DataFrame.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
xtrain = df[df[['Shop_name','Bikes_available','Shop_location']].notna().all(axis=1)]
```